# how do I get jQuery and js working on heroku

Tags: php, jquery, heroku

I am new to Heroku and trying to get my app working on it. All works fine except non of my scrips are working. I have a PHP header file that provides all the links to e.g. jQuery etc. which I have stored in the js directory.

```
<title><?=$head_title;?></title>
<link href="css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/animatedcollapse.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have an apache dyne (heroku-php-apache2) and a ClearDB MySQL database. How do I get jQuery running on Heroku?

Comment: So Heroku doesn't do anything special for including jQuery. It's just a hosting platform. If you have a folder called `js/` with `jquery.min.js` in it, then jquery will work just fine. Just make sure your dyno definitely has those files on it, and make sure your path to the script is correct. Look at the Network Tab of your Dev Tools on the browser you are using. Do you get red 404s for all the loaded scripts and css?

Comment: no 404s, actually, that showed me that jQuery is running fine but there was another issue in one of my files. All sorted, thanks!!